# Is it safe to call ExecutorService.shutdown() and awaitTermination() from a different thread than created the ExecutorService?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, executorservice

I create the ExecutorService on Thread A, then Thread B calls `shutdown()` and `awaitTermination()` on the ExecutorService.

Assuming all tasks have been already been submitted prior to Thread B's creation, and no new tasks will be submitted, is there any danger?

I'm guessing it's fine, but it never hurts to ask.

Comment: For simplicity - can you post some code to see what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

As you guessed it is absolutely fine to call ExecutorService shutdown() and awaitTermination(..) on the ExecutorService from Thread B.

Infact in the usual usage of ExecutorService, one thread takes care of adding all the thread tasks to the executorservice and then the same thread initiates a graceful shutdown() and then awaitTermination(..). So in your case you are just creating ThreadB to do your shutdown tasks.

Ideally it would be better to not submit your ThreadB to the same ExecutorService which it would try to shutdown() which I believe you would have taken into consideration.